# ng g module my-module only generates the module.ts file

Tags: angular, command-line-interface, angular-cli, angular-module

ng g module my-module only generates the module.ts file. But I need all the files css, HTML, ts, spec, module.ts.
How can I generate all of them at a time using cli?

Comment: I'm guessing you actually want to generate a *COMPONENT*: `ng g c my-component`

Comment: No, I want component with module.ts at a time.

Comment: oops sorry, bro. I am just a beginner, never mind.

Comment: Please "upvote" and "accept" altoqueperro's response, if you found it helpful.

Comment: I tried to upvote but poops up a message like "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputations are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Comment: Thank you for trying, I didn't realize "upvotes" were restricted.  Q: Did you try "Accept"?

Comment: You are welcome. I can't find "Accept" anywhere.

Comment: You figured it out :)  Just mark the "check" icon beside the answer :)  "Accept" does several things: 1) it helps point other folks with the same question to the answer that helped you most, 2) It rewards points - and says "Thank you!" to the person who responded, and 3) it "cleans up" your question, rather than leaving it in "unanswered" limbo.

Comment: You are awesome! Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do by angular cli cmd ,but it will take two steps/cmds separately or one cmd line union by and &:

first create module with/out routing as you preferred:

```
ng g m /pages/home-page --routing=true
```

then in a second cmd just create component:

```
ng g c /pages/home-page
```

or you can combine cmds in one cmd with && operator:

```
 ng g m /pages/home-page --routing=true && ng g c /pages/home-page
```

Angular cli will automatic include your component to the module that you create in first cmd, if you don't want to angular auto import ,just add --skip-import options:

```
 ng g c /pages/home-page --skip-import
```

Comment: That's a better way. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this command:

```
ng g c [my component]
```

this generate those files except the module, if you need the module you can generate with the command you already using.

hope this helps.

Comment: I know it creates a component, I wanted to know is there any way to create all the files including module at a time.

Comment: As far as i know angular doesn't generate those files together, the you can use ionic framework on top on your project, when you run `ionic g page [my-page]` this will generate all those file you asking for.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a 3rd party library. I've written one and you can try it (there are others out there). I'll describe how to do it using my schematics library:

### Step one: Install the library as a dev dependency:

```
npm i --save-dev @julianobrasil/schematics-components
```

### Step two: Create your component + module, including routing

```
ng g @julianobrasil/schematics-components:component-module --name my-data --path views
```

Parameters used in the example:

- **my-data:** name of the component that will be created in this case
- **views:** the folder where `my-data` will live (relative to the `app` folder)

Description => The above command will create:

- A module
- A component inside the module
- A façade service, already injected in the component
- A `@angular/material` module (remove it if you aren't using `@angular/material`)
- A routing module and a routing component (the module is ready to be lazy-loaded)